# What are Forms in Lists?

Tags: list, form

What are **Forms** in Lists? What are the Forms **available** in Lists? And What is "**InfoPath**"? How is it related to Forms?

Comment: Please do not ask so broad questions, and do not post multiple questions in the same post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With regards to SharePoint, there are 3 forms for each list. These are the `NewForm` (adding a new item to the list), `EditForm` (editing an existing item in the list), and the `DispForm` (or Display Form, which is just viewing the list entry). With SharePoint Enterprise, you can edit the appearance of how these forms look if you don't like the default SharePoint forms, and this editing is done through Microsoft InfoPath. You can also set up rules for certain fields (like a Time In cannot be before a Time Out) to make your form safer.

Now what is InfoPath? InfoPath is a form designer which allows the designer to establish and create data connections for fields in a SharePoint list, SQL database, etc. Microsoft actually has 2 InfoPath applications: InfoPath Designer, and InfoPath Filler. InfoPath Filler basically allows for data to be entered in the published form's fields and submitted to wherever the data connection exists.

Hope this helps you understand.

Answer (score 2):

**Forms** for List / Library like `Add - Edit - Display` that can be customized by InfoPath.

[image]

By default, when creating or editing items, all of the fields in the list appear in a basic two-column layout table. this is the default New Form show all fields below each other as shown.

[image]

And this is the New form look likes after simple customization using InfoPath

[image]

InfoPath is not used to only customize and brand GUI form , but you can use it for form validation , and create rules ... etc.

Check also [How to use InfoPath to customize forms in SharePoint](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HSyrqbgLdbs)

**Note :**

- to use Infopath services you must have a SharePoint EnterPrise Edition.
- Also, there is not InfoPath 2016 for more details [check SharePoint Designer 2016 and InfoPath 2016 in SharePoint Server 2016, What’s the alternatives ?](https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/05/06/did-you-consider-powerapps-is-a-replacement-for-sharepoint-designer-and-infopath-in-sharepoint/)

Comment: I still didn't get to know what exactly is InfoPath. I have customised my Form View using Design Manager. So what's the difference between using InfoPath and Design Manager? Or is it like they both are same or something?

Comment: InfoPath for customizing the SharePoint form , design manager is a new feature in SharePoint 2013 to brand your SharePoint site to create a custom master page and page layout this operation can't be created from InfoPath .